# Is it possible to run a for loop after a for loop in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

This might be a dumb question but is it possible to run a for loop after a for loop is done executing?
I have a code but it doesn't seem to be running after the other for loop is done

```
var alphabet ='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
var arr=[];
var sorting=[];
for(x=0;x<15;x++) {
    arr.push(prompt("Enter your name in the format, First Name, Middle, Last:"));
    var converter=arr[x].toLowerCase();
    var name=converter;
    document.write(name + "<br>");

}
for(y=0;y<15;y++) {
    var name1=arr[y].toLowerCase();
    var laster=name1.lastIndexOf(" ");
    var sorterz=laster.substring(laster+1,laster+2);
    var finder=alphabet.indexOf(sorterz);
    sorting.push(finder.item)
    document.write("ok");
}
```

Comment: I see only 1 `for` loop in the code. If you meant running the same for loop many times, then either put a `for` loop around it, or put the loop in a function and call the function many times.

Comment: short answer: yes. Also, I only see one for loop in your posted code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't worry, we've all been there.

The answer to your question is yes, the for loop after that should run but why is it not running in your code?

After running your code [here](https://codepen.io/vpalyer8/pen/MWwBRwO?editors=0001) in codepen, I noticed that there is an error message in the console.

> Uncaught TypeError: laster.substring is not a function   at pen.js:0

If you were to do `console.log(laster)`, you should see that it is a number.

To fix your error, just simply change `laster.substring(laster+1,laster+2);` to `name1.substring(laster+1,laster+2);` and your for loop should work accordingly.

Whenever you find that your javascript is not working, it is helpful to check the console of the web browser that you are using. 
I've included the guides on how to use the consoles for popular browsers.

[Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console)

[Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Console)

[Edge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/devtools-guide/console)

All the best to you in your journey in coding. We, programmers, are life long learners.